# Hammerjs pan return all events

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I am using jQuerys plugin with Hammerjs.

```
$('.grab').hammer().on('pan', function(ev){console.info(ev));
//(44) pan
```

This will always return "pan"

How can I get it to return the different events as [given here](http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-pan/) from `ev.type`

```
panstart
panmove
panend
pancancel
panleft
panright
panup
pandown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it to return the different events, you need to register each event type like this:

```
$('.grab').hammer().on('pan panstart panmove panend pancancel
                        panleft panright panup pandown',

    // Handler
    function(ev) {
        console.log(ev.type);
    }
);
```

A quick test shows this emits the specific event type (`panleft`) first and then the general `pan` event after.

Here's [Hammer's example page](http://hammerjs.github.io/examples/) which links to a ["Basic Vertical Pan Example"](http://codepen.io/jtangelder/pen/ABFnd)

Comment: Perfect, heh hadn't thought about tht :O